# How can I always have one type of activity in the background, even if other activities are launched?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So let's say I have 3 types of activities, each with their own manifest file and intent filter:

- HomeActivity
- ProfileActivity - (deeplink url path: /profile-view)
- SearchActivity - (deeplink url path: /search-view)

In my app, users can deep link into the ProfileActivity or SearchActivity directly via intent-filters. However, when this happens, there is no HomeActivity in the backstack. I want to ensure the HomeActivity is launched in the backstack whenever a non-Homeactivity is launched. How can I do that?

I was thinking of somehow checking if HomeActivity exists, and if it doesn't exist, launch that first?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Android Navigation Component.](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) This library handle's deep links gracefully. Take a look at here: [Create a deep link for a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link).

> When a user opens your app via an explicit deep link, the task back stack is cleared and replaced with the deep link destination. When nesting graphs, the start destination from each level of nesting—that is, the start destination from each  element in the hierarchy—is also added to the stack. This means that when a user presses the Back button from a deep link destination, they navigate back up the navigation stack just as though they entered your app from its entry point.